# Simplest way to style/present ComboBoxItem in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, combobox

What is the simplest way to customize the content display of ComboBoxItem?  I would like to present a list of font names, with each item drawn in the appropriate font.
I suspect I need something like

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="{TemplateBinding Content}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
```

Where would that go?
Can I create a control template for ComboBoxItem, and use it for only selected ComboBoxes?
Thanks for any hints....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silverlight 3 does not have implicit styling, so if you create a style with a ControlTemplate to accomplish this, you would have to explicitly assign it to the ComboBox.  No worries about it getting accidentally picked up.

I was able to achieve this with the following XAML inside the ComboBox, bound to an `ObservableCollection<string>`:

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock FontFamily="{Binding}" Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Obviously, the Binding would probably need a property name if you're binding to something more complex, but this allowed me to see the various selections in their own font.

You could also refactor this either into a `DataTemplate` or a style if you find yourself reusing it.

Comment: Good answer, I was going to suggest the Item source be a collection of `FontFamily` but this works just as well.  Has me wondering how the string gets converted to a `FontFamily` when assigned to the `FontFamily` property, I can't see where that is done unless the default binding handles that implicitly.  Can't find where that is documented though.

Comment: There must be an implicit Binding Converter to handle it.  Given that you can specify it as a string in XAML and have it correctly look up the right font, it's probably flowing through the same mechanic.